# Portfolio duration

Tags: fixed-income, portfolio-management, duration, bond-portfolio

What is the correct way to calculate duration of a fixed income portfolio with long and short bond positions? And how to calculate portfolio YTM with long and short positions. For long only (or short only) we use weighted average duration and yield but how to calculate with long and short position?

Answer (score 2):

You do it the same way as with long only as weighted sum of the durations of each position.

You have two possibilities for calculating the weights:

**long/short with respect to a benchmark:** 
then take as basis the dollar value of your portfolio P USD, set the benchmark to the same dollar value and calculate each weight as fraction of the position $w_i = P_i/P$ and long/short can be deviations from the benchmark. The sum of these weights is zero.

**long/short with derivatives:** 
So I assume you are long derivatives and bonds and short derivatives. Then you can again use the sum of your bonds as portfolio value in P USD. Then long derivatives have weights $w_i = MV_i/P$ and short derivatives have $w_i = -MV_i/P$. The sum of these weights (bonds + derivatives) can be positive, zero or negative depending on your position.

I would use the same weights for the yield.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, in the situation with long bonds and short derivatives (bond futures), what exactly do you mean with dollar value of portfolio P ? In case of beeing long in bonds, it equals the bond price. But it is unclear to me, what it stands for in the case of being short in bond futures ? Also what does the MV mean in case of being short bond futures ? Thank you.

Comment: Also, could you please comment, whether the sum all of weights (across all positions - long bonds and short futures) must always be equal to 1 for the whole portfolio or not necessarily ? Thank you.

Comment: $P$ is the sum of the market values of all your bonds. $MV_i$ is the market value of derivative $i$. E.g., P = EUR 1 mio, then you might by future short with market values EUR 100 000. This would mean that these futures have a weight of -10%. Your exposure is roughly 90% (100% - 10%).

Comment: You can assume that the sum of the weights of your cash (non derivative) positions is 100%. The futures can be viewed as some exposure on top (-x% or +x%). This is, in my oponion, a useful view on the exposure of your portfolio.